# Bash Script to Detect Clamshell State

Tags: bash, scripting

I am trying to get a script working that will detect the state of the clamshell on a macbook and if closed, force-logout any logged in user.  I could use some help with the script.  Not only is the script not functioning as intended, I am not even getting any logs created.  The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

log="/Library/Logs/Auto_Logout/Auto_Logout.log"

function writelog () {
    DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S)
    /bin/echo "${1}"
    /bin/echo "$DATE" " $1" >> "$log"
}

function auto_logout () {
    log stream --style syslog | grep --line-buffered 'clamshell closed: YES' | \
    while read -r; do
        loggedInUser=$(/usr/bin/python -c 'from SystemConfiguration import SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser; import sys; username = (SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser(None, None, None) or [None])[0]; username = [username,""][username in [u"loginwindow", None, u""]]; sys.stdout.write(username + "\n");')
        if [[ -n "$loggedInUser" ]]; then
            writelog "Lid has been closed while $loggedInUser is still logged in; logging out."
            launchctl bootout gui/"$(id -u "$loggedInUser")"
            writelog "Done."
        else
            writelog "Lid has been closed without anybody logged in, taking no action."
        fi
     done
}

mkdir -p /Library/Logs/Auto_Logout

# Run once - Launch daemon will run it every 60 seconds
auto_logout

done
```

Update:  if I close the lid, wait a couple minutes, and then reopen the macbook, the login screen presents, and visually, there are no indicators that any of the users are currently logged in. However,

If I issue a 'last' command, I see that several users are listed as still logged in, including the one that was logged in when the lid was closed, and

If I look in the Users directory, the Guest folder is still there, which it should not be if Guest was properly logged out.

Worth noting: the Auto_Logout log shows an entry for each time the lid was closed, and claims to have logged out the user each time. That seems to be in conflict with the results of both 'last' and 'w'.

Comment: Question are you running the script under a specific users account?  And if not Admin, does that user have permission to write to the logs without Admin privileges?

Comment: Further -- I am no Mac expert, but if it's standard as in Unix/Linux -- I would be sure to run the `cron` as `root` (`sudo` of course) since this is an administrative task that manages multiple users.  (If you're not already doing that, that is)

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  The script has currently been chmod'd to 777 to ensure there are no permissions issues, and the script is called by LaunchDaemon, which runs as root.

Comment: Have you attempted `echo` statements in your script?  They will be written to the `mail` file for that user during a `cron` run.  The mail file for `root` or `LaunchDaemon` can be found at `/var/mail`  And it will contain the process (start / stop)  and echo statements / errors from the `cron` job and it's sub-processes (At least on Unix / Linux).  This can be very useful in debugging.

Comment: @Zak The script seems to be writing to the log file sufficiently well, but the forced logout seems to only be half working.  I am taken back to the login screen when I reopen the lid but last and w commands reveal that the user is not logged out...